# Remember me functionality

Tags: remember-me

I have been trying to make "Remember Me" work for the frontend user using

```
<input type="hidden" name="auto_login" value="0">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="auto_login" value="1"/>
```

Based on the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html), it seems to me that "Remember Me" is only mentioned in the "Control Panel Session Type, Cookies Only" option.

Does this mean that "Remember Me" does not work for User Session?

EDIT:

Looking at  *Admin -> Security and Privacy -> Cookie Settings*, all the fields are blank. Does this cause a problem?

Answer (score 1):

"Remember Me" works with the Control Panel Session type set to Cookies Only: 
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html